# Keyboard shortcut to select full file name including extension

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-mate, cinnamon, nemo

Is there a shortcut to select the full name of a file when copying or renaming using a graphical interface?
<kbd>F2</kbd> only select the file name excluding the extension.

Answer (score 4):

In Nemo and Nautilus (not in Thunar), you just have to press <kbd>F2</kbd> twice after selecting the file.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up discovering by chance using (Mate) Caja, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

1. press <kbd>F2</kbd> for the renaming dialog to show up
2. when the dialog is present, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all)